# Cannot get more than 1 Mbps with Intel Wireless-AC 9560 on Ubuntu 18.04 for 5 GHz band

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-driver

### Problem and details:

- Very slow Wi-Fi speed on the 5GHz band in ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
- I can get better speeds with the 2.4GHz connection (say > 60 Mbps).
- I have 1Gbps rated internet connection
- I can get up to 600+ Mbps when I boot to windows.
- My Motherboard: Asus Tuf Gaming z390 Pro Wi-Fi

### What I have tried:

- I have tried all the solutions mentioned in this post, [Speed Up Slow Wi-Fi Connection In Ubuntu Linux](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/), and nothing worked.

### sudo lshw -C network output

```
  *-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 20:79:18:bd:cd:79
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-17-generic firmware=38.c0e03d94.0 ip=10.0.0.72 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a4334000-a4337fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 10
       serial: 04:d4:c4:01:26:f4
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:125 memory:a4300000-a431ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:03:f0:87:49
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: you should of asked this question here: https://askubuntu.com/ your problem is clearly not computer related since windows gives you respectable speeds

Comment: I think you actually have the [Asus Tuf Gaming Z390**M** Pro WiFi](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/TUF-Z390M-PRO-GAMING-WI-FI/) (note the **M**), as the [Asus Tuf Gaming z390 Pro](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/TUF-Z390-PRO-GAMING/) does not appear to have Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

I started randomly getting slow speeds on one of my laptops, which also has the Intel AC 9560 card; I was running Windows, but adapting my solution may work for you.

1. Set that wireless cards advanced settings to Prefer 5 GHz networks
2. In your router's advanced WiFi settings, set the WiFi channel manually to something above channel 48 and less than 68 (36- 48 is for home/domestic use, so they get a bit congested). This way, you'll be on a channel that no one is likely to use.
3. Restart the laptop, and the speeds should hopefully go super fast.

My guess is out of the blue (probably after a windows/driver update), the WiFi card starts to get lots of interference with any channel that has other users/congestion on it.